# Histidine Chemfig from a Picture

Tags: chemfig, mol2chemfig

The last one from this picture set. I have this Histidine which I have already done a series of questions.  I did what I knew this time:
I need help to finish the triangle that is in the histidine.  Also if I were to publish these notecards would that be possible? I could do it some where, if you kept up with the questions.

```
    \begin{flashcard}
        {
            \chemfig{H_3N^{+}-C(-[2]H)(-[6]CH_2(trianglething))-C(=[1]O)(-[7]O^-)}
        }
    Done
    \end{flashcard}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution with `chemmove`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\chemfig{NH(-[4]@{a})(-[:165,0.22,,,draw=none]^{+})
    =[:60,,1]-[:120,,,1]NH-[4]@{b}-[2]CH_2
    -[2]C(-[2]H)(-[4,0.9]H_3N^{+}|\vphantom{C})
    -[0]C(=[1]O)
    -[-1]O|^{-}}
\chemmove[-]{
    \draw (a) -- (b);
    \draw ($(a)+(2pt,2pt)$) -- ($(b)+(2pt,-2pt)$);
}

\end{document}
```